# Passing text value to thymeleaf view in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, controller, thymeleaf

```
@RequestMapping(value = "alphabet")
public String index(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("title", "Alphabet");
    return "categories/index";
```

We are at the ${title} page

I'm trying to get title to display within html tags. Is there a way to do this in spring boot?

Comment: there is.. read [the docs](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmvcaccessdata.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah so this is absolutely possible in Thymeleaf. What you can do is change the title using the title tag and text parameter. It is important to note that `th` will stand for the thymeleaf xml namespace. It it also important to note that this can be done with [fragments](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-thymeleaf-fragments).

```html
<title th:text="${title}></title>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the th:text attribute as `th:text="${title}`

DOCS: https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standarddialect5minutes.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `th:text` parameter for thymeleaf

```html
<p align="center">We are at the <title th:text="${title}></title> page</p>
```

Find more details in [doc](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmvcaccessdata.html)

Comment: @AxelKong did you try this solution ?